# Why am I getting this error in python: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 of Hearts'

Tags: python, blackjack

I am writing a Python code for a Black Jack game, and I am getting an issue when trying to append an index of a variable to another variable. I define these variables in seperate functions, but I have set them as global in each function. This is the code snippet that is giving me the error.

```
def GiveCard():
    global ValuePla1 #define variables as global
    global ValuePla2
    global ValuePla3
    global ValuePla4
    global ValuePla5
    for i in playerlist: #loop to iterate over each player
        index=FinalDeck.index(random.choice(FinalDeck)) #get index of random card
        print("Player", i, "card is", FinalDeck[index]) #print random card based on index
        FinalDeck.pop(index) #delete 1the card that was printed in the line above
        card=FinalDeck[index] #save printed card to variable so that that variable can be accesed by the following if statements
        if card[0]=="A": #If selected card is ace, ask whih value the player wants it to have
            AceChoice=int(input("Do you want your ace to equal 1 or 11?"))
            if AceChoice == 1:
                card=1 #save chosen value to 'card' so that it can be appended to the player value list
            elif AceChoice==11:
                card=11
        if i == '1': #check which player/index currently on, then append only the number to the playervalue list
            ValuePla1+=int((card[0])) #append the first value of the card (the number) to the value list and make it a integer
            continue
        elif i == '2':
            ValuePla2+=int((card[0]))
            continue
        elif i == '3':
            ValuePla3+=int((card[0]))
            continue
        elif i == '4':
            ValuePla4+=int((card[0]))
            continue
        elif i == '5':
            ValuePla5+=int((card[0]))
            continue
```

I have tried setting the variables to global variables before initializing them, and setting specific variables to integers, to make sure that there is no issue adding a number to a variable.

Comment: Provide the full error message. because it says exactly where the error occurs. Also, try stepping it through a debugger to inspect what your variables are through the loop.

Comment: Other than the answer below, your lines `FinalDeck.pop(index)` followed by `card=FinalDeck[index]` are probably not what you intend to do. You're removing the object and then trying to get it from the index when its no longer there. You probably want to reverse the order you've written those two lines in (Or if `FinalDeck` is a list `pop` will return the value so you could just write `card = FinalDeck.pop(index)`

Comment: Try changing the code so you would have a class for players and a class for the game. Then you can play around with objects more easily.

Comment: when you do `if AceChoice == 1:  card=1`  you are assigning an integer to card. Your card data type is inconsistent, since now is no longer a string, and doing card[0] would result in an error. I would strongly recommend that you use classes, so your card is a class instance from which you have different methods like `getValue`, `getSuit` etc...

Comment: `if i == '1'` `if i == '2'` `if i == '3'`: have you heard of lists?

Comment: In blackjack you don't ask a player whether they want their ace to count as 1 or 11. You assume 11 as long as that does not amount to more than 21. And if with later dealt cards, 21 is exceeded, you should still replace that 11 by 1 (if it was 11).

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with the global variable rather the conversion that you are doing, the issues lies with the conversion of the character to integer type.
i.e probably your `card[0]` contains the value `2 of Hearts` instead of string `2`, hence when you are trying to convert the whole sentence it is throwing errors. 
Try replacing `int((card[0]))` with `int((card[0][0]))` or `int((card[0].split()[0]))` for every occurrence in the given code snippet, i think that will fix your issue.